# Un - Community Wiki an answer

Tags: support, community-wiki

[I wrote this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/15532/396) and after 10 revisions it went Wiki.

Can I make this un-Community Wiki this to collect rep ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, neither the question nor the answer is a wiki now. Perhaps someone already changed it back.

PS: If this happens again, please just flag the posting.